# Expressing as Big O notation

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, big-o

So I understand that if the two while loops were just while (x < n), that it would be expressed as O(n^2), but with the divide by two, how do I put that into my equation? Thanks

```
    int result = 0;
    int x = 0;
    while (x < n / 2){
            result += arr[x];
            x += 1;
            while (x >= n / 2 && x < n){
                    result += arr[x];
                    x += 1;
            }
     }
     printf("%d\n", result);
```

Comment: Why don't you rewrite the code as `while (x < n)` for the outer loop, and eliminate the inner loop? It will be `O(n)`.

Comment: I'm supposed to just evaluate it as is, not rewrite it

Comment: Hint: the product between a linear function and a constant is still a linear function.

Answer (score 0):

The program snippet actually compues a sum of the elements of the array.
If n is the number of elements, then it runs the first loop n/2 times and inner (second) loop n/2 times, totaling n times, thus, it is O(n).
Let's explain step by step with an example:
say,

```
int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}; 
int n = 5;
```

These are steps of execution:

```
1. (first loop) arr[0](10) is added, result becomes 10, x becomes 1
2. (first loop) arr[1](20) is added, result becomes 30, x becomes 2
3. (first loop) arr[2](30) is added, result becomes 60, x becomes 3
4. (first loop) arr[3](40) is added, result becomes 100, x becomes 4
5. (first loop) arr[4](50) is added, result becomes 150, x becomes 5
```

Thus, first loop executes for floor(n/2) times i.e. 2 times (step 1, 2)
while at step 2, it runs second inner loop (x >= n/2 i.e. x>= 2), and second loop runs for ceiling(n/2) i.e. 3 times (step 3, 4, 5) and both the loop ends
Thus, overall time complexity is O(n).
But, this could have done simpler like:

```
 int result = 0;
 int x = 0;
 while (x < n){
  result += arr[x];
  x += 1;
 }
 printf("%d\n", result);
```